# How do I write to a python file using a command in another python file?

Tags: python, overwrite

I am making a program that takes passwords and can make new ones. I want to be able to save passwords that I have made in one file as a part of a string in a list in a different file.

The list.append() method won't work because after I close the program and run it again, the list gets redefined with what was originally in it; ie, the predefined passwords I have written into the program.
if it helps, here it helps.

```
passkey_has_been_made = True
number_of_times_that_someone_entered_the_wrong_key = 0

def sleep(secs: float) -> None: ...

def make_new_password():
    create_password = input("Create a new password: ")
    password = None
    if len(create_password) > 16:
        print("Password cannot be longer than 16 characters!")
    else:
        password = create_password
        key_list.append(str(password))

while passkey_has_been_made:
    action = input('what would you like to do?')
    if action == 'load new password':
        pass_key_check = input('enter an administrative password')
        if pass_key_check in file2.admin_passkey:
            make_new_password()
    elif action == 'log in':
        if number_of_times_that_someone_entered_the_wrong_key < 5:
            
            pass_key_check = input('enter your passkey\n')
            
            if pass_key_check in file2.key_list:
                    print("Access Granted.\n")
                    input("Press enter to continue.")
                    break
            else:
                number_of_times_that_someone_entered_the_wrong_key += 1
                print('invalid\n')
        else:
            print('to many attempts! System shutdown!')
            sleep(10)
            print('rebooting...')
            sleep(2)
            number_of_times_that_someone_entered_the_wrong_key = 0
```

```
#file2
key_list = ['password']
admin_passkey = [key_list[0]]
```

Comment: "Write to a Python file" is a bad idea. Don't even try; keep code and data separate, and keep your data in a format -- JSON, SQLite, &c -- that doesn't allow execution.

Comment: From a security perspective, if a service has enough permissions to rewrite its own source code, any successful attacker is guaranteed to have arbitrary execution capabilities even if the vulnerability they've found otherwise only permits filesystem write with the service's own permissions (which in general should be tightly constrained).

Comment: Why not save these lists within a DB? even if it's a local flat file DB like a simple sqlite (if that makes sense for you)

Comment: If you don't like the idea of a database, even JSON would work.